# 8GB Nextbook8 only showing .98GB internal storage

Tags: nextbook-premium-8

Running 4.4.2 KitKat. Does the OS really take up 7GB? I've only got like 5 games downloaded and already running out of space for apps. :(

Comment: Is "Does the OS take up 7GB?" actually your question, or do you have a more substantial one?

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange.

Android partitions are an odd subject, especially when you're used to Windows-esque devices.  Android runs on a version of Linux, and it's root directories are split up into partitions on your device.  When a manufacturer says their device is 8GB, they mean exactly that - in total, you have 8GB.

All the Linux partitions on your device each have their own allotment of storage space.  For example, /recovery may take 200MB, /cache may take 1GB, etc etc.  Long story short is this: with an 8GB tablet, yes, the OS will take up a substantial amount of storage space.  I'm guessing you have around 1GB free to install applications.